# AngularJS IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea

When shall I use New Project and when shall I choose the options from left hand side from the main page of IntelliJ when creating a project.

Different files are created when running project. These are based on the selection made using creation time.

Comment: you can choose new dynamic web project and then add ui application in web-inf folder or web content folder then you can run it on any server you can see the result, but index,jsp/html should be your default page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please make sure that you’ve installed AngularJS plugin: go to `Preferences | Plugins`, `Install JetBrains plugin...` and search for **AngularJS**.

Once the plugin is installed, you can use `New Project | Static Web | AngularJS` to create [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) project stub; or, if you like to start with [Angular2](https://github.com/angular/angular) project, try `New Project | Static Web | Angular CLI` (Note: it requires [Angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli))

Note that you don't necessary need using these options; you can create a new empty **Static Web** project (`New Project | Static Web | Static Web`) in Idea and start populating it with your stuff

Comment: Please I have already the angular plugin installed in my IDE, I have just created a new project and now I want to add angular and bower to it. How can I do that?